# How do I add the "Accept-Patch" header to my response to an OPTIONS request?

Tags: http, flask, httpresponse, http-method, http-options-method

I am using Flask. I'm lost as to how to add an "Accept-Patch" response to any OPTIONS requests my server might get.

Would it be something like this (I tried this and while it worked, I'm not sure if this is allowed):

```
class MyViewMixin(MethodView):
    def options(self, id):
        response = make_response('This works!', 200)
        response.headers.extend({'Accept-Patch': '*'})
        return response

    def get(self, id): #same for post, delete, put, patch
        #stuff here#
```

Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Your solution is right, Please read this link:http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.make_response

Comment: Yeah, that's where I got the initial idea. Thanks for confirming!